# Why MQTT is disconnected by Keep-Alive?

Tags: mqtt, keep-alive, mosquitto

I am using Mosquitto.

The client set the MQTT's Keep-Alive to 120 seconds.

Keep-Alive waits for 150% of 120 seconds or 180 seconds, so I don't think it's going to be disconnected.

However, if you send PINGREQ every 121 seconds, the connection will be maintained and randomly disconnected.

Sending PINGREQ every 119 seconds will not disconnect.
Why does this happen?

Comment: The mosquitto logs will include the reason why it has disconnected the client. Edit the question to include the logs. Also if you have set a Keep-Alive time of 120 seconds why would you deliberately wait longer (even if the broker chooses to enforce at 150% the time)